# Wordpress: how to debug "Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM."

Tags: wordpress

After upgrading Wordpress to 5.8 and CiviCRM to 5.39.0, the event registration page does not work.

This is the url:

- MY-SITE/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=120

These are the symptoms:

- the h1 of the page is "CiviCRM"
- the body of the page is "Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM."
- the title tag in the header contains the title of the event
- no profile fields, hence no possibility to register for the event.
- no errors in ConfigAndLog
- no javascript errors in browser web developer tools
- several cache clear had no effect

What could be the cause of this error? What can I do to debug this further?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd try flushing WP permalinks first.  Go to https://mysite.org/wp-admin/options-permalink.php   Just visiting the page should flush the permalinks.  No need to save anything.  If that fails, I'd delete the dirctories under `templates_c` to ensure the CiviCRM cache is fully cleared.

Comment: One other thought:  is the base page set here:  https://mysite.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=civi_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to comment out line 526 from /includes/civicrm.basepage.php

```
remove_filter('the_content', [$this, 'basepage_render']);
```

That should solve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tommy! Commenting out that line and clearing WP and civi caches solved the problem.

Comment: @AlainB are you using Divi or Avada Theme?

Comment: @TommyB  Are you finding this problematic on all sites or just those using themes like Avada and Divi?

Comment: @KevinCristiano only Divi so far -- I only suspect avada --- This plugin looks like the long term solution https://github.com/phdccltd/civicrm-539-wp-content-fix

Comment: @TommyB It seems that the guy who made the site used the Ken theme.

Comment: Thanks @TommyB  I am reluctant to have CiviCRM support all the cases that Page builders and themes put out there.  If needed a plugin would be preferable to us playing whack-a-mole on this.  Thanks for confirming where you've seen it.

Comment: Thanks @TommyB for the solution